# Return String from Java stream

Tags: java, string, return, java-stream

I have a class `Person`, which stores the code of each person and a list of friends. I'm trying to get the code of the person with the highest number of friends, but cannot figure it out. The methods `getFriends` and `getCode` are provided by the `Person` class.

How can I return a string from the stream?

```
HashMap<String,Person> persons = new HashMap<>();

public String personWithLargestNumberOfFriends() {
    return persons.values().stream()
        .sorted(comparing(p -> ((Person)p).getFriends().size()).reversed())
        .limit(1)
        .forEach(p -> ((Person)p).getCode());
}
```

Comment: Regardless of what you want to do with a Stream, as soon as you forget about the existence of `forEach`, solutions will arise…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of sorting, use [`max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-).

```
return persons.values().stream()
    .max(comparing(Person::getFriends, comparingInt(List::size)))
    .map(Person::getCode)
    .orElse("empty code");
```

See the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class to see if some other getter would suit your needs, like `orElseThrow()`.